# How to get all the items of a taxonomy even if it does not have a custom post type?

Tags: php, taxonomy

How do you get get all the items of a taxonomy even if it does not have a custom post type?

I tried :

```
<?php
 $termsq = get_terms("competence");
 $countq = count($termsq);
 if ( $countq > 0 ){
     echo "<ul>";
     foreach ( $termsq as $termq ) {
       echo "<li>" . $termq->name . "</li>";

     }
     echo "</ul>";
 }
 ?>
```

but, it just displays the taxonomy that contains a custom post type. 
I want to get the complete taxonomy, even if it has no custom post type related to it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `hide_empty` argument:

```
$termsq = get_terms("competence",array('hide_empty'=>false));
```

[See the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms#Parameters) for the complete argument list.

Additionally, `get_terms` will return a `WP_Error` object on failure, so your `count` check won't work. You need [`is_wp_error`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_wp_error).

```
$termsq = get_terms("competence",array('hide_empty'=>false));
if (!is_wp_error($termsq)) {
  echo "<ul>";
  foreach ( $termsq as $termq ) {
    echo "<li>" . $termq->name . "</li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
```